# Thymeleaf does not work with Lombok getters and setters

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, lombok

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mytemplate' of bean class [at.test.Mytemplate]: Bean property 'mytemplate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Cause: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'
```

Class

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Mytemplate{

    String name;

}
```

HTML

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" method="POST" role="form" th:action="@{'/save'}" th:object="${mytemplate}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{mytemplate.name}" required="required"/>
</form>
```

Any idea why I get this error? Why I could not use lombok with thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1):

The error states `Bean property 'mytemplate' is not readable`, it's not saying anything about the `name` property - `at.test.Mytemplate` itself is used as the root for thymeleaf to start variable resolving.

So just reference `name` instead of `mytemplate.name`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}" required="required"/>
```